# Функция блокировка изменения размера окна в Qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Существует ли функция в PyQt5 блокировка расширения окна как в tkinter `.resizable(False, False)`?

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root = QMainWindow()
root.resize(500, 700)
root.setWindowTitle('Детские кружки')
root.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: `setFixedSize` - метод `QWidget`

Comment: А если требуемый размер неизвестен и вы используете компоновщик (`QLayout`), то `QLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)`

Comment: @mkkik можете объяснить как его добавить в мой код( дополнил вопрос)

Comment: Замените вызов `resize` на `setFixedSize` с теми же параметрами.

Comment: @mkkik Благодарю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функцией `setFixedSize(x, y)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root = QMainWindow()
root.setFixedSize(500, 700)
root.setWindowTitle('Детские кружки')
root.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: а если потом надо изменить окна. то есть например пока не надо изменять его размер но потом нужно его изменить?